# How to display username from login to home component?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, angular-components

I have two components: login and home. After the user logs in, it is redirected to home-report page.

The **login.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSnackBar, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
usersLogin: any;
testUser:any;

  ngOnInit() { }

  userLog: string;
  passLog: string;
  submitLoading = false;
  messageError: string;
  messageOK: string;
  data: any;

  constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar, private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) { this.testUser="bla"}

  // ********Login***********
  onSubmitLogin(usersLogin: { userLogin: string, passLogin: string }) {

    const headerDict = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    }
    
    const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
      headers: new HttpHeaders (headerDict), 
    };

    this.http.post('http://localhost:54111/api/Login', usersLogin, requestOptions).subscribe(dataLogin => {
 

      console.log( usersLogin.userLogin);// this usersLogin.userLogin i want to display on toolbar
      console.log("True or false: "+dataLogin)
      this.testUser=usersLogin.userLogin;
      console.log("testUser: "+ this.testUser);

      if (dataLogin) {
            this.snackBar.open('Login Successful', '', { duration: 1000 })
            this.router.navigate([`Home`]);
          } else {
            this.snackBar.open('Login error', '', { duration: 1000 })
          }
    })     
  }
```

I want to display on toolbar the username (`usersLogin.userLogin`) that has logged in. I am able to display `this.testUser="bla"` on toolbar.

The **home-report.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-report',
  templateUrl: './home-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-report.component.css'],
  providers: [LoginComponent]
})
export class HomeReportComponent implements OnInit {

  userLogged: any;
  usersLogin: any;
  constructor(private utiliz: LoginComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     
    this.userLogged=this.utiliz.testUser;//this displays "bla" on my toolbar  
  }
}
```

The **home-report.component.html**:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>Toolbar</span>
    <div>
        <mat-icon>account_circle</mat-icon>
        {{userLogged}}
    </div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

So my question is how could I get the `usersLogin.userLogin` from `onSubmitLogin(...)` method in order to display it in home-report component?

Comment: You need a global state management. I will not advocate for any. In general  after login, you set the current user to the state and read it wherever you want.

Comment: @SvetoslavPetkov It's not so clear to me your solution. So how should I do it? Thanks for replying!

Comment: Example global state management: https://ngrx.io/ . But you can pick whatever you like. I cannot create a state management crash course for you, but I believe there are plenty of free available online.